# DefaultOidcUser cannot be cast to class CustomOAuth2User

Tags: java, spring-boot, backend

I have the following success handler that is part of the WebSecurityConfig.java file:

```
            .successHandler(new AuthenticationSuccessHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                                Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {

                CustomOAuth2User oauthUser = (CustomOAuth2User) authentication.getPrincipal();

                userAuthService.processOAuthPostLogin(oauthUser.getEmail());

                response.sendRedirect("/list");
            }
        })
```

At the line where casting is supposed to take place, it gives the error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: class
> org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.oidc.user.DefaultOidcUser
> cannot be cast to class
> com.myapp.myapp.mvc.business.domain.user.CustomOAuth2User

**How can I go about solving this?**

The CustomOAuth2User class is as follows:

```
public class CustomOAuth2User implements OAuth2User {

    private OAuth2User oauth2User;

    public CustomOAuth2User(OAuth2User oauth2User) {
        this.oauth2User = oauth2User;
    }


    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> getAttributes() {
        return oauth2User.getAttributes();
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return oauth2User.getAuthorities();
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return oauth2User.getAttribute("name");
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return oauth2User.<String>getAttribute("email");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You are getting this error because you have not defined the scopes explicitly in your app and by default scopes also include openId.
If you define your scopes in the `application.properties` like below you can cast the principal to `CustomOAuth2User` .

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.scope=email,profile
```

If you wish to include openId in your scopes, then you need to cast your principal to `DefaultOidcUser` an you can create a `CustomOidcUserService` service like below

```
@Service
public class CustomOidcUserService extends OidcUserService {

  @Autowired private UserRepository userRepository;
  @Autowired private RoleRepository roleRepository;

  @Override
  public OidcUser loadUser(OidcUserRequest userRequest) throws OAuth2AuthenticationException {
    final OidcUser oidcUser = super.loadUser(userRequest);
    return oidcUser;
}
```

Comment: This is the right answer. I was missing the scope parameter in my yaml file.

google:
                        clientId: clientid
                        clientSecret: secret
                        scope:
                            - email
                            - profile

Answer (score 5):

I think your code are from codejava.net right? I also got the same issues and I fixed with update on the onAuthenticationSuccess function. I change the following code

```
CustomOAuth2User oauthUser = (CustomOAuth2User) authentication.getPrincipal();

userAuthService.processOAuthPostLogin(oauthUser.getEmail());
```

with this code

```
DefaultOidcUser oauthUser = (DefaultOidcUser) authentication.getPrincipal();
String email = oauthUser.getAttribute("email");
userDetailsService.processOAuthPostLogin(email);
```

And it's working now :)